# htaccess for creating clean url for application hosted on sub-domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here are a few examples of the urls that are generated by this application on which am working. I want to make the url clean, using htaccess:

Example: http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?folder=abc&file=xyz&variable1=pqr&variable2=123

The final url should looke like:
http://subdomain.domain.com/abc/xyz/pqr
Basically all parameters should appear after forward slash.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look [in this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?folder=$1&file=$2&variable1=$3
```

Comment: Let me check. Amidst, please note, the urls are dynamically created and they may or may not have a file or variable/s. And also the variable name changes depending on the click.

Comment: This should work, for this url after the domain: 'abc/xyz/pqr'. Did you placed the htaccess file at the right place in your subdomain?

Comment: I placed it in the folder subdomain_domain_com